# Change default Wordpress email notification for Woocommerce notification

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, notifications

I have a question about the email notification, after the registration new customer or the recovery password whatever with the order or registration. The website sent me a default WordPress notification.

[image]

In Woocommerce Settings>E-mail, I am already set up with emails notification

and it should look like that:

[image]

*I already setup SMTP with plugin WP Mail SMTP.*

Thanks for help

Comment: You want to edit the email template coming from woocommerce?

Comment: no I  already edited email but it always sent default from wordpress